# R search Number between two others in a vector

Tags: r

I work with Rand I have two vectors

```
> k_anfang
[1]   11 1723
> k_ende
[1]   14 1725
```

I want to have:

```
11,12,13,14,1723,1724,1725
```

to skip these rows in a loop

How I get the numbers between the two vectors?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
k_anfang <- c(11, 1723)
k_ende <- c(14, 1725)

c(k_anfang[1]:k_ende[1], k_anfang[2]:k_ende[2])
```

Other option (in inspiration from @Jilber) is

```
unlist(mapply(seq, k_anfang, k_ende))
```

... and another one

```
unlist(mapply(`:`, k_anfang, k_ende))
```

Comment: I like your `mapply` solution +1!

Comment: It came in my mind after seeing your `sapply` solution.

Answer (score 2):

A fancy way to do it:

```
> unlist(sapply(1:length(k_anfang), function(i) k_anfang[i]:k_ende[i]))
[1]   11   12   13   14 1723 1724 1725
```

Note: this assumes `k_anfang` and `k_ende` both have the same length.